# grails delete id param before form submit

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-controller

I'm facing the following problem: I have entity that I want to edit. So I navigate to show page and then to edit page. Lets say **id** of my entity equals **2**. Then we have the following urls:
**app/entity/show/2** -> **app/entity/edit/2**. Then I update my entity on edit page and submit the form and go to **app/entity/update**.
In my controller I have the following code for update() method:

```
def update(Entity entity) {
//some code
}
```

I debug update method and see that entity contains **id = 2** which means that id is contained in the params (probably because previous url equaled **app/entity/edit/2**). And in fact it is in params if to check with debug. But I want to exclude **id** from params before submiting the form because Grails does something that is not suitable for me: if **id** is in params grails fetches the entity along with its associations from DB. Lets say we have **one-to-many** association **1:entity-N:otherEntity**, on my edit page it is possible to delete some **otherEntities**, but since **id** of the **entity** comes within params, grails fetches those **otherEntities** even if they were deleted on edit page. So is it possible to exclude **id** of the entity from params before form submit?
Thanks!

**UPD**

In my edit.gsp there were the following code:

```
<g:form url="[resource: empInstance, action: 'update']" method="PUT">
```

I changed it to

```
<g:form controller="emp" action="update" method="PUT">
```

and now id is not contained within params but this code:

```
def update(Entity entity) {
    //some code
    }
```

gives an empty entity

Comment: please show your code, part related to submit

Comment: You can do some processing via interceptor http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/beforeInterceptor.html before executing an action.

Comment: I did not get this : "on my edit page it is possible to delete some otherEntities" and on the second case you did get empty object because you omit resource: empInstance which contains appends the id field to the url.

Answer (score 0):

If you omit the id, how are you going to update the instance? All you will have is the other properties - where do you plan on storing those?

Grails is retrieving the instance because you told it to by adding `Entity entity` as an argument to your controller action. When you do that, the data binding code looks for an `id` parameter and if it finds one, will use the request class to get the instance. If you don't want it to load the instance, remove that argument and work directly with `params`.